# How to redirect user with POST data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I need to redirect user to external url with POST data. How could I achieve this in ReactJS?

I need to redirect the user to external bank deposit link. I thought bank link will respond whit redirect url but it doesn't. My thinking is that I need to make a POST request to that bank link and redirect user to that page. Tell me if I'm wrong. Here is what I've tried so far.

This redirect happens in dispatch so rendering a form is not an option

```
fetch(body.success.message.redirect_url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(body.success.message.request_data)
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  throw error;
});
```

Comment: Please provide your  use case. What are the urls? same domain? same site? redirect with react router or window.location changes? Did you try somthing already?

Comment: Edited my question @DamienLeroux

Comment: `fetch` is to fetch. It can't redirect user: only fetch data from a distant url. What are the current url and the destination url? Are you using react-router already?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form element and submit it. This is how [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) does it. Obviously you need to rewrite this basic code to react, but you get the idea.

```
  var href = body.success.message.redirect_url,
    form = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>'),

  form.hide().appendTo('body');
  form.submit();
```